# How to force to open a web page in external browser even if Popup Browser is enabled in Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: android, webview

#### Expected Result

To open a webpage in external built-in browser (not popup window) when clicking a link in a web view.

#### Problem

When Popup Browser is enabled in Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-N7100), the web page is opened in the Popup Browser, and I don't want this. I want the web page to be opened in external built-in browser even if the Popup Browser is enabled.

The setting of Popup Browser in the Samsung Note II can be found at Settings -> Application manager -> ALL -> Popup Browser.

#### IDE

- Android version = 4.1.1
- Device = Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-N7100)

#### Code

```
public class PeppermintWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

//....

    private void handleOpenBrowserScheme(String url){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        intent.setData(uri);
        mainActivityInstance.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue here.  Did you ever find a solution?

Just for the record, to clarify the reason why this is an issue:  On Samsung Galaxy Note II, these kind of intents are handled in a pop-up web browser rather than the full app.  But for security reasons, https links don't always open properly.  This is especially an issue if you are redirected due a wi-fi network's login page (in this case, you need to launch the real browser to proceed with the network login).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem clearly but may this help you:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse((String) i.getExtras().get("url")));        
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

where "url" is the URL to which you want to go in your browser.
And i is an INTENT that holds the "url" from another activity.
Can this help you?

Comment: Sorry. I thought that would help you.